# How to include recyclerview in bottomsheet?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a linnear layout at the top of recyclerview. I used nestedscrollview to drag it from bottom. When linear lyout reaches the top scroll behaviour of recyclerview should activated. Top linear should act as toolbar. I want bottom sheet similar to google maps navigation screens bottomsheet.
Thanks in advance

Comment: hve u found answer to your question? plz share

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can go with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. This will fulfill your requirement.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

           //your linear layout content will be here 

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I wanted sliding up behaviour to show direction information same as google map does. I used third party library to implement that                                    Thank u for response.