# Android Bottomsheet (NestedScrollView) disable scroll on expanded state

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479423/how-to-include-recyclerview-in-bottomsheet)

I want to achieve a bottomsheet behavior like google map app shown in gif image (not talking about 2 state bottomsheet behavior).

[image]

I want bottomsheet to stop scrolling when it is in expanded state. In gif image it is shown that when user swipe bottomsheet up to expanded state then bottomsheet stop scrolling further and then content inside the bottomsheet start scrolling. Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="co.com.parsoniisolutions.custombottomsheetbehavior.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy_framelayout_replacing_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <include
            layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_content_sroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In include xml file i have a layout and a scrollview below it. I want layout to act as a thumb or peek area of bottomsheet and when bottom sheet starts to expand, hide toolbar and when it reaches the expanded state, it should not further scroll, instead inner scrollview should start scrolling. In my code it keep scrolling up even after bottomsheet reaches the expanded state instead of inner scroll. Any help?